# Unable to use SurfFeatureDetector in OpenCV 3.0.0

Tags: linker, surf, opencv3.0

System-

1. Windows 8.1 64 bit machine
2. OpenCV 3.0.0
3. Visual Studio 12 2013

I have built the openCV 3.0.0 with the contrib modules. However, when I compile this code I get errors.

```
#include <OpenNI.h>                     //used for taking in input from xtion pro live
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>  
#include <opencv2\core\core.hpp>        
#include <opencv2\features2d\features2d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/features2d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/xfeatures2d.hpp>      // these are the libraries in the new location     (they contain SURF implementation)
#include <opencv2/xfeatures2d/nonfree.hpp>

using namespace std;
//using namespace openni;
using namespace cv;

int main(void)
{
    //from sample code 
    int minHessian = 400;

    SurfFeatureDetector detector(minHessian);

    return 0;
}
```

The error is-

> error C2065: 'SurfFeatureDetector' : undeclared identifier

Comment: take a look [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/52001/how-to-compile-nonfree-module-in-opencv-30-beta/?answer=52002#post-id-52002)

Answer (score 4):

The syntax to construct a Surf feature detector in OpenCV 3.0 is different from 2.x versions.

```
Ptr<SURF> surf=SURF::create(minHessian);
std::vector<KeyPoint> keypts;
Mat desc;
surf->detectAndCompute(img,noArray(),keypts,desc);
```

Apologies if the above example would still throw any errors, I don't have a working version to field test it.

Comment: that's right, here is an example: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/xfeatures2d/samples/surf_matcher.cpp

Comment: I can't find 'xfeatures2d.hpp' inside opencv2 for the OpenCV 3.0 I installed. Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

I think for SURF you must use 'extra' modules. Have a look on that: https://github.com/itseez/opencv_contrib/

Basically what you need to do is download the code (opencv_contrib). Add it to the list of modules in the opencv source folder. Then, in cmake you must add the path < opencv_contrib >/modules into EXTRA_MODULES_PATH. Finally, after generate the project via cmake, you will find the xfeatured2d (I think is the one you need) on your opencv solution and you will be able to build it and use them.

Answer (score 0):

In opencv3.0, it combined all library in opencv_world300d.lib (debug) and opencv_world300.lib (release).
For this, you can use #include to instead other include.
On the other hand, they are  opencv_world310d.lib (debug) and opencv_world310.lib (release) in opencv3.1.